# NullPointerException with an array of objects

Tags: java, object, oop

I dont know why std[i] is null which is making an error
Error :
student 1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Student.setName()" because "[0]" is null
at Main.main(Main.java:7)
Student class :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Student {
    
    private String Name;
    private int [] Marks = new int [3];
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    public void setName () {
        System.out.print("Enter Name : ");
        Name = in.nextLine();
    }
    public void setMarks () {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter Mark "+ (i+1) +" : ");
            Marks[i] = in.nextInt();
        } 
    }
    public Student () {}
    public Student (String Name, int [] Marks) {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Marks = Marks;
    }
    public float AVG () {
        int Sum = 0;
        for (int i : Marks) {
            Sum += i;    
        }
        return (float) Sum / 3;
    }
    public void INFO () {
        System.out.println("Name : "+ Name);    
        int c = 1;   
        for (int i : Marks) {
            System.out.println("Mark "+ c +": "+ i);
            c++;
        }
        System.out.println("AVG of "+ this.Name +": "+ AVG());
    }
}
```

Main class :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        Student [] std = new Student [3];
        for (int i = 0; i < std.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("student "+ (i+1));
            std[0].setName();
            std[0].setMarks();
            std[0].INFO();
        }
    }
}
```

the code was working when declarating one object only but it is not working with an array of objects

Comment: *Student [] std = new Student [3];* You don't then create any instances of `Student` and store them in the array. Also, yes, when you've solved that, don't hardcode the index as @NathanHughes said. And watch your [naming](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions). *INFO* (never method names in upper case. only the names of constants) should be `toString()`

Comment: The array initialization won't create each instance, you'll have to manually do this before using the _set_ methods.  This is unlike primitive array initialization, which will set all values to _0_.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing just a few things, here you go:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < std.length; i++) {
        std[i] = new Student();
        System.out.println("student "+ (i));
        std[i].setName();
        std[i].setMarks();
        std[i].INFO();
    }
```

Teh first thing was creating the object instances, the other thing was referencing them with 'i' instead of 0;

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in how you initialize and use the std array of Student objects in the Main class. The for loop inside the main method always uses std[0] to access the elements of the array, so all other elements (std[1] and std[2]) remain null. This causes a NullPointerException when trying to call a method on a null element. To fix the error you can use this code snippet.

```
for (int i = 0; i < std.length; i++) {
        std[i] = new Student(); // Initialize each element of the array
        System.out.println("student " + (i + 1));
        std[i].setName();
        std[i].setMarks();
        std[i].INFO();
}
```